# How to see the set of plugins chosen by babel-preset-env?

Tags: babeljs

Take a babel config using the [env preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env/), like this:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "node": "10.6"
      },
      "modules": false
    }]
  ]
}
```

In this case, the target is Node 10.6 with the `--experimental-modules` flag enabled.

I'm curious to see the list of actual Babel plugins the above config would resolve to. Is there some way to do this? (Not just for this case, but for any Babel config.)